# Postgres "column $3 does not exist" when using parameters

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am running into an error when trying to use parameters as part of my query.

Noteworthy parts of my schema are:

`name_tokens tsvector`

`cards.rarity card_rarity` which is a custom enum created from:
`create type card_rarity as enum ('C', 'T', 'R', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'F', 'P');`

The troublesome query is:

```
SELECT cards.* FROM cards WHERE
(name_tokens @@ to_tsquery("$1"::text)) AND
(cards.rarity = "$2"::card_rarity)
      ORDER BY cards.id;
```

with input of:

```
[ 'absorb & in', 'L' ]
```

When I run this, the error states:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: column "$3" does not exist`.

When I run this query without parameters it works fine, ie:

```
SELECT cards.* FROM cards WHERE
(name_tokens @@ to_tsquery('absorb & in') AND
(cards.rarity = 'L')
      ORDER BY cards.id;
```

I would like to be able to utilize parameters as throwing user strings into a query directly can be dangerous.

Any ideas on why I'm getting this error? I'm assuming it's some incorrect formatting or use of quotes when I shouldn't or something. Any help is appreciated :)

Edit:
It was suggested that I tried:

```
SELECT cards.* FROM cards WHERE
(name_tokens @@ to_tsquery($1::text)) AND
(cards.rarity = $2::card_rarity)
ORDER BY cards.id;
```

But when I do this, I get the following error:
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: could not determine data type of parameter $1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL uses double quotes for identifiers (such as table and column names) so this:

```
SELECT cards.* FROM cards WHERE
(name_tokens @@ to_tsquery("$1"::text)) AND
(cards.rarity = "$2"::card_rarity)
      ORDER BY cards.id;
```

contains two quoted identifiers `"$1"` and `"$2"` but no numbered placeholders.

If you want to use numbered placeholders, drop the double quotes:

```
SELECT cards.* FROM cards WHERE
(name_tokens @@ to_tsquery($1::text)) AND
(cards.rarity = $2::card_rarity)
      ORDER BY cards.id;
```

I'm not sure where it is getting `"$3"` from though, I'd guess that the error is coming from a different query with a similar quoting error.

Comment: When I try that I get the following error:
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: could not determine data type of parameter $1`

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right query? The type casts generally take care of that sort of issue.

Comment: Yes. This the line I'm calling the query:
`await pool.query(searchQuery.getSearchQuery(), searchQuery.getInputs());`

Where searchQuery.getSearchQuery() returns:
`SELECT cards.* FROM cards WHERE (name_tokens @@ to_tsquery($1::text)) AND (cards.rarity = $2::card_rarity)`

and the input returns:
`[ 'absorb & in', 'L' ]`

I'm using the pg package from npm for the pooly.query.

Comment: And what happens if you `pool.query('SELECT cards.* FROM cards WHERE (name_tokens @@ to_tsquery($1::text)) AND (cards.rarity = $2::card_rarity)', [ 'absorb & in', 'L' ])` directly?

Comment: Okay, that does work... why would that be? When I build the string for the query it seems to not like it for some reason :/

Comment: So if have the query string be a constant static string it works. But if it's a string that I generated through logic and return it then it doesn't work. I'm quite confused by that...

Comment: Okay! I figured it out! So my `.getSearchQuery()` was being called again. And unfortunately it's not a true 'getting' in that it alters the state (which I should fix) which was resulting in an incorrect string the 2+ times it was called.

Comment: Nice, good to hear. Sorry was playing D&D all afternoon. Does that also explain the odd `$3` problem?

Comment: Yes I believe so, it was adding additional inputs each time it was called. All fixed now! Hope D&D was fun!